# Creating HiveContext in spark application on oozie

Tags: apache-spark, hive, oozie

We are running a spark application using oozie. In the application we are creating hiveContext.
When running the application with spark-submit everything works fine, but when run it with oozie we get the following exceptions :

```
2018-01-16 17:45:24,762 [Driver] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore  - 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2018-01-16 17:45:24,795 [Driver] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore  - ObjectStore, initialize called
2018-01-16 17:45:24,994 [Driver] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2018-01-16 17:45:24,995 [Driver] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence  - Property hive.metastore.integral.jdo.pushdown unknown - will be ignored
2018-01-16 17:45:25,439 [Driver] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore  - Retrying creating default database after error: Error creating transactional connection factory
javax.jdo.JDOFatalInternalException: Error creating transactional connection factory
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:587)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:781)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.client(ClientWrapper.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:478)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at com.frontline.shopfloor.integration.Integration$.main(Integration.scala:41)
    at com.frontline.shopfloor.integration.Integration.main(Integration.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:552)
NestedThrowablesStackTrace:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:325)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.registerConnectionFactory(AbstractStoreManager.java:281)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.<init>(AbstractStoreManager.java:239)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:631)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:301)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.createStoreManagerForProperties(NucleusContext.java:1069)
    at org.datanucleus.NucleusContext.initialise(NucleusContext.java:359)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:768)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:326)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1965)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1960)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1166)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:808)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:701)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:682)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:709)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:78)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:6319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:207)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:273)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.client(ClientWrapper.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper$$anonfun$withHiveState$1.apply(ClientWrapper.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.liftedTree1$1(ClientWrapper.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.retryLocked(ClientWrapper.scala:238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.withHiveState(ClientWrapper.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runHive(ClientWrapper.scala:488)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.runSqlHive(ClientWrapper.scala:478)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:443)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$4.apply(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
    at com.frontline.shopfloor.integration.Integration$.main(Integration.scala:41)
    at com.frontline.shopfloor.integration.Integration.main(Integration.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:552)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.<init>(BoneCPDataSource.java:64)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.BoneCPDataSourceFactory.makePooledDataSource(BoneCPDataSourceFactory.java:73)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.generateDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:217)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.initialiseDataSources(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl.<init>(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:82)
    ... 86 more
```

Oozie workflow :

```
<workflow-app name="Integration" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5"> 
<start to="IntegrationLayer"/>
    <action name="IntegrationLayer">
       <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.1">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>                  
            <master>${sparkMaster}</master>
            <mode>cluster</mode>
            <name>${appName}</name>
            <class>...</class>
            <jar>...</jar>
            <spark-opts>--executor-memory 3G --driver-memory 3G --conf "spark.yarn.historyServer.address=http://${nameServiceName}:18088" --conf "spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs://${nameServiceName}/user/spark/applicationHistory" --conf "spark.eventLog.enabled=true" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configurationog4j.properties" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"</spark-opts>
            <arg>${nameServiceName}</arg>
            <arg>${hdfsPath}</arg>
            <arg>${appName}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end-node"/>
        <error to="fail-node"/>
    </action>  
    <kill name="fail-node">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end-node"/>
</workflow-app>
```

We work with cloudera 5.8
Do we need to configure something else to run the application on Oozie ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mcve]. Select the code blocks and press `Ctrl+K` to format them.

Comment: Please share your oozie classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.MapMaker.makeComputingMap(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; from class com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource

This indicates that accessing makeComputngMap will fails. The makeComputingMap is no longer public method since guava version 15.0. The newer version of the guava version over shadows the old version which is used by the spark. Could you please check your spark classpath and keep the 14.0.1 version as first entry in classpath or replace with old version.

http://google.github.io/guava/releases/14.0.1/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

http://google.github.io/guava/releases/15.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html

Thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

You should add hive-site.xml in your oozie action.

Comment: I did it and didn't help, maybe I am doing it wrong, I took the hive-site.xml from the hive installation and put it in my hdfs and then in Oozie workflow I added <spark-opts>--files ${oozieLibPath}/hive-site.xml </spark-opts>. This didn;t chnaged anything, should I add it differently or edit the file itself somehow ?